# Ignore extra columns in CSV when using COPY FROM in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

I have a table with two columns `id, name` and I am ingesting data from a 3rd party that may add data to each row without my knowledge. I want to ensure the file still loads until I am ready to change my data model, ignoring any extra columns that are added to the end of each row.

E.g. If the csv file changes to `id, name, email` at some point, I want my COPY FROM query to continue happily loading `id, name`.

I've tried to implement `SKIPCOLS`, but as far as I can see, this only seems to work when there is a match between fields in the first place.

i.e. The following is the correct usage of COPY FROM with SKIPCOLS but will not help my needs as I can't seem to reference a column that only exists in the csv.

```
COPY users (id, name) FROM 'users.csv' WITH SKIPCOLS = 'name';
```

Is there another way to do this or a different way to use SKIPCOLS that I am missing?

Comment: What do you want, skip column that is not in present in the copy command ??

Comment: I want something like this...

`COPY users (id, name) FROM 'users.csv';`

where users.csv:

`id, name, email`

Comment: If the email field not present in your user table, it will not work

Comment: So unless i alter the table I have to manipulate the file outside of Cassandra before loading? This seems like a glaring mistake in the design of SKIPCOLS. I can't fathom to understand the few situations where it might be useful in its current form. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Yes, you have to modify the csv before loading. Or you can change cqlsh code.